# Compile PHP with Apache 2.4 handler

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I'm trying to compile PHP 5.4 with Apache 2.4 handler since it's not officially available (I know that apachelounge.com supplies it unofficially, but I don't need it! I need to compile it myself ).
I've included required Apache include/lib folders within PHP's deps folder, applied the submitted patch here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62267
And I got a successful build.

But unfortunately it didn't work for me (Apache not started), I keep getting the following error(s) in event log:

```
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 175 of /path/to/httpd.conf: Module "sapi\\apache2handler\\mod_php5.c" is not compatible with this version     .
```

---

```
>>> of Apache (found 20110619, need 20120211). Please contact the vendor for the correct version.
```

httpd.conf line 175:

```
LoadModule php5_module ../../php/php-5.4.5/php5apache2_4.dll
```

What's wrong with it? Any suggestions??

Comment: Why do you have to do it yourself?

Comment: What about learning how to do it myself?! Well I've others reasons as well!!

Comment: Honestly, if you're learning how (and I'm guessing new to this), I wouldn't experiment with versions that aren't official available.  Try something that's been field-tested where people have worked out the weird errors.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But as soon as apachelounge.com did it, then it's possible & it's method should be well known/tested. I've asked them as well. I'll appreciate your help if you mentioned any suggestions.

Comment: Well known/tested/(documented) **!==** possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, bug fixed & new patch file submitted to the bug report @ php.net

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62267